# Laravel 5.2 authentication doesn't work with implicit routes under prefix group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I have used the make:auth command to create the authentication system, and it has been working fine

I have created another Restful controller, and I've been using the Route::controller on routes.php

like this code, Please read the // comments in the code

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); // working fine and requires logging in
    Route::get('test', 'HomeController@index'); // working fine and requires logging in
    Route::controller('account','accountController'); // doesn't work and I can visit this page without logging in
});
```

I see the implicit routes doesn't working fine with middleware, but I don't know the appropriate solution

Comment: you need to have "auth" middleware instead of "web" for pages that you want to have authentication.

Comment: Are Implicit controllers deprecated from Laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need `auth` middleware instead of web for authentication:

```
Route::get('profile', ['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
     Route::controller('account','accountController');
}]);
```

Another option is to set this in the controller.

```
class accountController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new accountController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, the browser redirect well to logging page but I got "The page isn't redirecting properly", and the page didn't work at all

Comment: I found your answer is the best solution for the problem, by adding the $this->middleware('auth'); in the construct function in the controller file, without changing my routes file at all

Comment: No problem. Glad it was helpful. You can get a list with "php artisan route:list" to see every route along with their middleware. This is very helpful to see if any of them overlapping or missing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Can, The solution is by adding this code in the controller file

```
class accountController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new accountController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

  ...
  ...
}
```